# How to iterate over each 2 elements in a list, python3?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

```
for element1 in list_of_elements:
    for element2 in list_of_elements:
        if not element1 == element2:
             #do
```

I need a better solution, this cycle goes twice over the list.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 1):

```
for element1, element2 in permutations(list_of_elements, r=2):
    #do
```

It is a solution.